# How to regex replace where replacement is a function of search keyword/tag

Tags: python, regex

I want to regex replace in Python where replacement is a function of tag's suffix

Suppose I have a text (or XML) where I can define my own tags which I want to replace. Here is text example:

```
  <del:DeliveryFormat>A</del:
  <del:ReadingStartDate>%%%NOW@0@%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%%%</del:ReadingStartDate>
  <del:SpSla />
  <del:RecordPosition>1</del:RecordPosition>
  <del:Values>
    <del:Value position="1" registrationDate="2019-02-01T05:09:11.000+00:00" requestedReadingDate="%%%NOW@-1@%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%%%" reading="126.0" status="10" meterReadingId="677947381" />
  </del:Values>
```

Please note: that I'm free to choose tag format and I just chosen "%%%"

Please notice this two (and in reality more) different tags:

`"%%%NOW@0@%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%%%"` I want replace this with date NOW minus 0 days and make it in format `Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ`

`"%%%NOW@-1@%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ%%%"` I want replace this with date NOW minus 1 day and make it in format `Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ`

format may be different every time so it has to come form tag itself

For this operation is only beginning of the tag common (%%%NOW) and closing part (%%%). Suffix of the tag should be flexible and I want to have logic (function) that defines how to replace it based on that suffix.

I don't have any code to show - of course I've easily created how to replace `%%%NOW%%%` with date-time now in particular format. But how to make replacement value and format be function of tag's suffix - i have no idea :(

Of course I could probably work around it by looping/replacing for multiple searches like `%%%NOW@0@%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ, %%%NOW@-1@%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ, %%%NOW@-2@%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ,` etc... including different format strings. But could that be done with some intelligent beauty?

Comment: "re.sub" can take a function as "repl". This function gets a match object, can do calculations based on it and return appropriate replacement.

Comment: how about just use xml api and have default  time format like in python

Comment: @Michael Butscher thank you for a hint. Do you happen to know any relevant example of it? I'll search for it ofc now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it:

```
output_file_as_string = re.sub("%%%([a-zA-Z]+)@(.?\\d)@([^>]*)%%%", lambda match: Helpers.add_step_to_time(NOW,"day",int(match.group(2))).strftime(match.group(3)), input_file_as_string)
#input_file_as_string = <del:ReadingStartDate>%%%NOW@-2@%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+01Z%%%</del:ReadingStartDate>
#output_file_as_string = <del:ReadingStartDate>2019-06-11T12:20:47+01Z</del:ReadingStartDate>
```

where "add_step_to_time" is function that already exists in my code.